# Not able to see apache axis2 wizard on eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I put jar file org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.6.0.jar and org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.6.0.jar into myeclipse\dropins folder and also setted Axis2 preferences successfully, but I am not able to see Axis2 wizard while creating new project

Answer (score 0):

For getting this option, you need a **download zip folder** from the below url - **unzip it** and place it under **dropins** folder in eclipse.
        From there on, eclipse will be capable of showing that option on menu. **But Default NO**.

Click [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/plugin-installation.html)

Comment: Other way i know is, you can install the Xcarecrows 4 WS 1.3.0 from the marketplace to get the axis2 features.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by placing below jar file in dropins folder
**axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** and
**axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**